# Canon SDK Initialisation Crash

Tags: c++, sdk, crash, access-violation

im currently trying to use the Canon SDK in C++.
*It's indeed the first time I use a SDK and im a begginer in C++.*

The problem is that when i try to initialize the SDK with the `EdsInitializeSDK()` function it instantly crash, here is the errors messages :

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA34E0121C (EDSDK.dll) in CameraTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000B44D4740.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA34E0121C (EDSDK.dll) in CameraTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000B44D4740.

Heres the entire code here :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "EDSDK.h"
#include "EDSDKTypes.h"
#include "CameraModel.h"
#include "CameraModelLegacy.h"
#include "CameraController.h"
#include "CameraEventListener.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsCameraListRef cameraList = NULL;
    EdsUInt32 count = 0;
    EdsCameraRef camera = nullptr;
    bool isSDKLoaded = false;

    err = EdsInitializeSDK();
    system("pause");
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "SDK INITIALISED" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "SDK INITIALISATION FAILED WAIT FOR EXIT" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(84);
    }
    cout << err << endl;
    err = EdsGetCameraList(&cameraList);
    cout << err << endl;
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Camera List Ok" << endl;
        err = EdsGetChildCount(cameraList, &count);
        cout << "Count : " << count << endl;
        if (count == 0) {
            err = EDS_ERR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "No Camera List" << endl;
    }
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "It worked" << endl;
        err = EdsGetChildAtIndex(cameraList, 0, &camera);
    } else {
        cout << "It didnt worked" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

If i remove the EDSInitializeSDK function, it don't crash.
Do you have an idea about whats the problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: Try something simpler: just call the initialization function and the release one. And check the documentation for those two functions.

Comment: @ZDF Thanks for your answer. I Already tried to do that, it still crash.

Comment: Is there something you’re supposed to set before calling the initialize function? Drivers? Other DLLs installed?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer is quite simple.
When i connect my camera, a software named "EOS Utility 3" shows up.
Its the problem, when I close it (and makes sure its realy close and not just reducted), it works.
Thanks for your help.
(I was using Canon EDSDK version 3.6.1 with a Canon EOS 1300D)